# wget permission issues

Tags: linux, wget, freebsd

Just to check: when using wget in linux or freebsd, if a file downloaded is pre-set to have some permission, uid number and gid number, does the file retain its permission in the downloaded client? I do not think so, but just to check.

Answer (score 1):

`wget` does not preserve owner, group or permissions of the remote file.